# Range of $f(z)=|1+z|+|1-z+z^2|$ when $ |z|=1$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, maxima-minima, absolute-value

> Find the Range of $f(z)=|1+z|+|1-z+z^2|$ when $z$ is a complex $ |z|=1$

I am able to get some weaker bounds using triangle inequality.

$f(z)< 1+|z|+1+|z|+|z^2|=5$

also $f(z)>|1+z+1-z+z^2|=|z^2+2|>||z^2|-2|=1$,but

these are too weak!.as i have checked  with WA

Is there an elgant solution using minimum calculus?. Substituiting $x+iy$ makes things very complex indeed.

Answer:
$[\sqrt{\frac{7}{2}},3\sqrt{\frac{7}{6}}]$

Comment: In fact, substituting $x+iy$ rather makes things very $\bf{real}$

Comment: That was supposed to be a pun :(

Comment: @User ohh! didn't get that

Comment: I don't have a rigorous proof, but I'm still going to leave this here if anyone else can take the following approach further.

Comment: I think this might helpful: The numbers $-1, -\omega, -\omega^2$ all lie on the unit circle where $\omega$ is the non-real cube root of $1$.

Comment: Let $A \equiv -1, B \equiv -\omega , C \equiv - \omega^2, P \equiv z $. With this, and since $|z|=1$,  the problem translates into finding the maximum and minimum of $|PA| + |PB||PC|$. I have tried to do this , but I haven't been able to prove it properly. Intuitively I guessed that $P $ should be $ B$ (or $C$) for minimum distance and it turns out to be correct but again, I can't rigorously prove it. For maximum, I can't even guess it. So I know this isn't a proper solution but if anyone knows how to take this approach and prove it rigorously, please do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $z=x+yi,$ where $x$ and $y$ are reals.

Thus, $x^2+y^2=1$ and
$$|z+1|+|1-z+z^2|=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(1-x+x^2-y^2)^2+(-y+2xy)^2}=$$
$$=\sqrt{2+2x}+\sqrt{(2x^2-x)^2+(1-x^2)(2x-1)^2}=\sqrt{2+2x}+|2x-1|$$ and we got a function of one variable $-1\leq x\leq 1.$

Can you end it now?

I got that the maximal value it's $\frac{13}{4}$ and occures for $x=\frac{-7}{8}.$

The minimal value it's $\sqrt3$ and occurs for $x=\frac{1}{2}.$

For the minimal value there is the following.

We need to prove that:
$$\sqrt{2x+2}+|2x-1|\geq\sqrt3$$ or
$$|2x-1|\geq\frac{1-2x}{\sqrt3+\sqrt{2+2x}},$$ which is true because
$$|2x-1|\left(\sqrt3+\sqrt{2+2x}\right)\geq|2x-1|\geq-(2x-1)=1-2x.$$
For the maximal value there is the following.

Let $x\geq\frac{1}{2}.$

Thus, $$\sqrt{2x+2}+|2x-1|=\sqrt{2x+2}+2x-1\leq\sqrt{2+2}+2-1=3<\frac{13}{4}.$$
Let $x\leq\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sqrt{2+2x}=y$.

Thus, $$\sqrt{2x+2}+|2x-1|=\sqrt{2x+2}-2x+1=\sqrt{2x+2}-2x-2+3=$$
$$=y-y^2+3=-\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{13}{4}\leq\frac{13}{4}.$$
The equality occurs for $y=\frac{1}{2}$ or $x=-\frac{7}{8}.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Your triangle inequality seems quite odd...

Answer (score 2):

Since $|z|=1$ we substitute $z=e^{i\theta}$, to get:
$$
f(\theta)=|1+e^{i\theta}|+|1-e^{i\theta}+e^{2i\theta}|\\
= \sqrt{ (1 + \cos \theta)^2 + \sin^2\theta} + \sqrt{(1 - \cos\theta+ \cos2\theta)^2 + (-\sin\theta + \sin2\theta )^2)}\\
=\sqrt{|2+2\cos\theta |}+|(1-2\cos\theta)|
$$
We can denote $u=\cos\theta$ and investigate $f(u)=\sqrt{|2+2u |}+|(1-2u)|$ for $u$ between $-1$ and $1$ by simple calculus. We get
$\max f=\frac{13}{4}$ for $u=-\frac{7}{8}$, and $\min f=\sqrt3$ for $u=\frac{1}{2}$. This does not agree with the answer given but I could not find any error.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $1-z+z^2=(1+r)(1+r^2)$ where $r$ is the cube root of unity.

Also, since $|z|=1$, $z\bar z=1$

Now rewrite the given expression as $√ (1+z)(1+\bar z) + √(1-z+z^2)(1-\bar z +\bar z^2)$

$\Rightarrow √ 1+z+\bar z+1 + √(z+r)(z+r^2)(\bar z+r)(\bar z+r^2)$

$\Rightarrow √(2+2\cos\theta) + √(z\bar z+zr+\bar zr+ r^2)(z\bar z+zr^2+\bar zr^2+ r)$

$\Rightarrow √(2+2\cos\theta) + √(2(r^2+r)z+2(r^2+r)\bar z +r+r^2+z^2+\bar z^2+4)$

$\Rightarrow √(2+2\cos\theta) + √(2(r^2+r+1)z+2(r^2+r+1)\bar z -1+(z+\bar z)^2-2z\bar z)$

$\Rightarrow √(2+2\cos\theta) + √((2\cos\theta)^2-3)$

$\Rightarrow (√2)\cos\frac{\theta}{2} + √(4\cos^2\theta-3)$

All that's left is minimising and maximsing this expression
which can be done with simple calculus.

**Appendix:**

$1-z+z^2=(z-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}=0$
$\Rightarrow z-\frac{1}{2}=±i√\frac{3}{2}$
$\Rightarrow z=\frac{1}{2}+(±i√\frac{3}{2})$

Comment: Are you a jee aspirant?

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore see my appendix

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore well I was, but now I am focused on KVPY, I want to go into Research in Physics. Previously I thought it would be impossible for someone like me to get top 150 AIR in KVPY (needed for IISc) so I just let my ambitions evaporate and just do what everyone else was doing and prepare for JEE. However all that being said KVPY preparation still overlaps quite a lot with JEE preparation

Comment: I got AIR 184 in KVPY and AIR 702 in JEE Advanced lol...

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore ah shit, I am an idiot. Well anyway I got the answer still but now it's debatable whether it's any better

Comment: @SoumyadwipChanda wow how much in maths jee adv

Comment: @Soumyadwip Chanda so did you mean to say that one can get an excellent rank in both? Well I know that and I haven't stopped my JEE preparation I just give it less importance and do some basic Olympiad type math and biology side by side

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore what about you? Are you completely focused on IITs? Which year are you giving JEE in?

Comment: next year! kvpy is very variable i am just going to write it.I aklso want to persue physics (quantum physics)

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore oh, I am still in XI. and yeah KVPY fellowship in XII is not so useful anyways. Well best of luck then for JEE 2021 then!

Comment: 78 marks in Mathematics... I also went to InMO and InChO OCSC camps... You can be an all rounder always lol

Comment: @Soumyadwip Chanda were you preparing from before XI?

Comment: Nope... only XI and XII

Comment: @Soumyadwip Chanda well I don't know what to say then.. people do work hard but aren't able to achieve this much this early. I feel the survivorship bias is at play here, maybe you should reflect on the possibility that you were smarter than many of your peers

Comment: I don't think working hard is the key... Here u have to identify the answer instead of finding the answer... Also they say that Coachings are a must... but I did it just by schooling without any tutions... And no other students in my area could clear JEE Advanced

Comment: @Soumyadwip Chanda "Here u have to identify the answer instead of finding the answer" that may be true for JEE Advanced (and even it is now slowly moving away from objective pattern and more towards integer/numerical questions) but you said that you also cleared INMO and InChO which are subjective and only 30 or so from India clear them

Comment: I went to the camps but couldnt clear it lol... Well...yea... one has to be smart

Comment: how is your jee prep going?

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore just fine I suppose, could get better but I have time right now to improve

Comment: @Ok how did kvpy go?

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore and btw what happened to your goal of pursuing Physics  (since in your profile you've mentioned IITM Chemical Engg and with that rank you could've gotten Physics at IITK too right)

Comment: @Amadeus yes decided not to go for physics as people scared me off!

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore though I cleared it I could not get desired rank at KVPY.. messed up a bit on exam day (though it's doubtful if I could get <150 air even then

Comment: @A It is very risky i realised any way chemical is good as most of it is applied physics and mathematical computation it is not chemistry like many think

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore but chemical engineers in IITs also more often go for non core jobs?

Comment: @Amadeus yeah but I want to do masters /phd in say MIT etc

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore a physicist should also be able to get those jobs. The differences I see are that a physics degree is harder thus requires more effort, and that you will earn peanuts in the duration in which you'll do your PhD- but ofcourse the flipside is that you'll, presumably, be doing what you love for 6 yrs so it won't matter

Comment: @Amadeus true but jee physics and real physics is very different ,that quantum mechanics of feynman drove me mad!!

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore I've heard many people in the physics programs in IITK/M have made it to the top universities; and btw I understand this conversation is not of much importance to you now as you've already made your decision (except ig a branch change after 1 yr?) but I also currently have the same goal of physics research thus it's important to me

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore yeah that is true it's very different. Actually I have been watching and reading stuff on modern physics since a long time, much before jee, and that's what got me interested in the first place, not my interest in jee type physics (which is great don't get me wrong but philosophically much less intriguing for obvious reasons)

Comment: @Amadeus well then go for  ur passion ,also consider engineering physics!