# Solving inequality involving complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

If z lies on the curve |z| = 1 such that $ a <|z + 1| + |1 + z^2 – z| <b $ then (a, b) can be

My approach

$Z=x+iy$

$X^2+y^2=1$

On arranging the given equation

---

a< $\sqrt{2+2x}+ \sqrt{2+x^2+2x^3-6x}$ <b

Further the only way I know is to differentiate to get min value which yields wrong answer . Any  better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $z=e^{it},\,t\in\Bbb R$ and $c:=\cos(t/2)$. We wish to constrain$$|1+z|+\frac{|1+z^3|}{|1+z|}=2|c|+|4c^2-3|$$for $c\in[-1,\,1]$, or equivalently $2c+|4c^2-3|$ for $c\in[0,\,1]$. This function is $3+2c-4c^2$ (maximal at $c=1/4$ with value $13/4$) on $[0,\,\sqrt{3}/2]$, but $-3+2c+4c^2$ on $[\sqrt{3}/2,\,1]$. On $[0,\,\sqrt{3}/2]$, the minimum occurs at $c=\sqrt{3}/2$ with value $\sqrt{3}$; on $[\sqrt{3}/2,\,1]$, the maximum occurs at $c=1$ with value $3$. So $a$ can be any value less than $\sqrt{3}$, while $b$ can be any value greater than $13/4$.

Comment: Actually this question has answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3865237/range-of-fz-1z1-zz2-when-z-1) but your method is much better(+1)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore am301's answer is similar.

Comment: yes similar but i generally dont like to use triginimetry in iinequalities as we bring in additional constriants...